# Populating a combobox with c# using MVVM paradigm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I want to display 'user groups' in a combobox, and bind the selected usergroup key to a variable in my view model.  I am using the MVVM paradigm, and I know it is very close to working but i just can't see where the issue is.  usergroups is is populated dynamically after a login via a web call.  I know the binding is working because if i remove the DisplayMemberPath attribute in the xaml, i see the groups.

my class UserGroup

```
public class UserGroup
{

    public long ugp_id;
    public String groupName;
    public float ugp_credits;
    public String logo;

    public UserGroup()
    {
    }
}
```

i have a xaml

```
 ....
 <ComboBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,4,0,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding userGroupCollection, Mode=OneWay}"
        DisplayMemberPath="groupName"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedUgpId}"
        SelectedValuePath="ugp_id" >
```

in my ViewModel Class i set up an observable collection :

```
  public ObservableCollection<UserGroup> _userGroupCollection;
  public ObservableCollection<UserGroup> userGroupCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _userGroupCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_userGroupCollection != value)
            {
                this._userGroupCollection = value;
                DynamicOnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

after the web call this data looks as I expect it to...

but when I look at the output window when the page is viewed i see the combobox entries are blank (but the correct number are shown) and this error:

```
'i3SoftClient.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: i3SoftClient.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ugp_id' property not found on 'object' ''UserGroup' (HashCode=29245900)'. BindingExpression:Path=ugp_id; DataItem='UserGroup' (HashCode=29245900); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'groupName' property not found on 'object' ''UserGroup' (HashCode=29245900)'. BindingExpression:Path=groupName; DataItem='UserGroup' (HashCode=29245900); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ugp_id' property not found on 'object' ''UserGroup' (HashCode=29245900)'. BindingExpression:Path=ugp_id; DataItem='UserGroup' (HashCode=29245900); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ugp_id' property not found on 'object' ''UserGroup' (HashCode=29245900)'. BindingExpression:Path=ugp_id; DataItem='UserGroup' (HashCode=29245900); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ugp_id' property not found on 'object' ''UserGroup' (HashCode=6695955)'. BindingExpression:Path=ugp_id; DataItem='UserGroup' (HashCode=6695955); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

I have looked around, but I just can't seem to understand the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it like this :

```
public long ugp_id { get; set; }
public String groupName { get; set; }
```

Try again now :)

What the error was that those wernt properties, those were mere variables :)
For Binding to work on any member, you should **declare** as above :)

Comment: BTW, you should either make your `UserGroup` class either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or make it immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use public fields for a binding. You must use properties

```
public class UserGroup
{

    public long ugp_id { get; set; };
    public String groupName { get; set; };
    public float ugp_credits { get; set; };
    public String logo { get; set; };

    public UserGroup()
    {
    }
}
```